# OpenMP parallel code has not the same output as the serial code

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, signal-processing, openmp

I had to change and extend my algorithm for some signal analysis (using the polyfilterbank technique) and couldn't use my old OpenMP code, but in the new code the results are not as expected (the results in the beginning positions in the array are somehow incorrect in comparison with a serial run [serial code shows the expected result]).

So in the first loop tFFTin I have some FFT data, which I'm multiplicating with a window function.

The goal is that a thread runs the inner loops for each polyphase factor. To avoid locks I use the reduction pragma (no complex reduction is defined by standard, so I use my one where each thread's omp_priv variable gets initialized with the omp_orig [so with tFFTin]). The reason I'm using the ordered pragma is that the results should be added to the output vector in an ordered way.

```
typedef std::complex<float> TComplexType;
typedef std::vector<TComplexType> TFFTContainer;

#pragma omp declare reduction(complexMul:TFFTContainer:\
        transform(omp_in.begin(), omp_in.end(),\
                omp_out.begin(), omp_out.begin(),\
                std::multiplies<TComplexType>()))\
                initializer (omp_priv(omp_orig))


void ConcreteResynthesis::ApplyPolyphase(TFFTContainer& tFFTin, TFFTContainer& tFFTout, TWindowContainer& tWindow, *someparams*) {;

  
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(tWindow) firstprivate(sFFTParams) reduction(complexMul: tFFTin) ordered  if(iFFTRawDataLen>cMinParallelSize)
    for (int p = 0; p < uPolyphase; ++p) {
        int iPolyphaseOffset = p * uFFTLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < uFFTLength; ++i) {
            tFFTin[i] *= tWindow[iPolyphaseOffset + i]; ///< get FFT input data from raw data
        }    

        #pragma omp ordered
        {
//using the overlap and add method
        for (int i = 0; i < sFFTParams.uFFTLength; ++i) {
            pDataPool->GetFullSignalData(workSignal)[mSignalPos + iPolyphaseOffset + i] += tFFTin[i];
        }
        }

    }

    mSignalPos = mSignalPos + mStep;
}
```

Is there a race condition or something, which makes wrong outputs at the beginning? Or do I have some logic error?

Another issue is, I don't really like my solution with using the ordered pragma, is there a better approach( i tried to use for this also the reduction-model, but the compiler doesn't allow me to use a pointer type for that)?

Comment: Have you tried parallelizing the inner loops instead of the outer loop? You would not need a custom reduction in that case nor would you need ordered.

Comment: The way I see it is that e.g. in the second thread (for example out of two), `tFFTin` starts with the same initial value as `tFFTin` in the first thread while it should start with the product accumulated in the first thread, therefore the values added to `workSignal` will be wrong.

Comment: @Zboson I didn't want to use it beacuse, I have read somewhere that paralellizing th einner loop does not scale as good as the outer loop.

Comment: @HristoIliev Well, I didn't see that. Is there a pragma for somehow passing ot to the other threads, or should I parallelize the inner loop as Z boson recommended?

Comment: I meant to try parallelizing the inner loop to see if you get the right answer. If you do then you learn something which may help you understand how to get the outer loop correct.If it's also fast then all the better. It's very simple to test.  You have to change a few lines of code and recompile.

Comment: @Zboson Oh, ok :). I will test it with the inner loop on Monday.And need to read some more literature :)

Comment: I agree that you should read some litterature. There is plenty of work about parallelizing the FFT (which is very hard because of the many data dependencies). There are also many different FFT algorithms (radix-n, mixed-radix, split-radix,...). I suggest that you at least take a look at [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) and [SPIRAL](http://www.spiral.net/codegenerator.html) (and their associated papers)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have implemented a very cool custom reduction for tFFTin. But this reduction is applied at the end of the parallel region.
Which is after you use the data in tFFTin. Another thing is what H. Iliev mentions that the second iteration of the outer loop relies on data which is computed in the previous iteration - a classic dependency.

I think you should try parallelizing the inner loops.